# How can you display the entire range of days on a chart, starting from the beginning and ending at the end, using the Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, charts, graphics

To visualize sales reports, I use a line graph. I'm using Vue.js. The data received from the server has the following format:

```
{
    "2024-02-01 00:00:00": "2550",
    "2024-02-05 00:00:00": "3415",
    "2024-02-07 00:00:00": "10770"
}
```

[image]

Note that the dates on the x-axis are displayed within the start and end dates provided by the server. However, I need to display the entire range of days from 2024-02-01 to 2024-02-29. If there is no data for certain days, I want the point on the graph to be placed at zero.

Here is my code:

```
chartData: {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
        aspectRatio: 3,
        color: '#2E436C',

        scales: {
            x: {
                type: "time",

                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    }
                },

                grid: {
                    display: false,
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
```

If there is a need to provide other code snippets, I will definitely share them.

Comment: Iterate through the data set and add missing days? Is that the question?

Comment: think about how a line chart works: it plots data points you give it drawing lines between them.  If you need a line to hit 0 at a certain point on your x-axis you need to add that as a data point, otherwise try something else like a bar chart where the 0 is implied.  For setting a specific range there are `min` and `max` options you can set, see the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-axes)